# how to decrepit pdf417 when read from barcode reader c#

Tags: c#-3.0

I have barcode reader for identity card and passport and 2d code , when read my card return text
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcXfU.png)
this string It's not understandable compared to real identity data
please help me to fix it in windows form c# Because it tired